# Error when connecting to both SQL Server and mySql using EF in C# Windows Forms application

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am developing a C# Windows Forms application and I am using Entity Framework 6 for its data access. I have 2 `dataContext` classes for accessing database, one of them is connected to a MySql database and the other one is connected to SQL Server database.

When I run my application, it first connects to Mysql and does its job with no error, but after that when it wants to connect to SQL Server, it throws an exception. I don't have error when it creates an instance of SQL Server `dataContext` class but when it wants to do any thing like reading on database it throws exception below :

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string
>
> Inner exception : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Comment: Can you show the connection string for SQLServer

Comment: mySql :
SERVER=*; DATABASE=*; UID=*;PASSWORD=*;Pooling = 'true'; convert zero datetime=True; Max Pool Size=10;Min Pool Size=0; charset=cp1256;port = 3306;Connection Timeout=3000

 //// 
sqlServer :
Data Source=*;Initial Catalog=*;User ID=*;password=*;

Comment: Are the databases running on separate servers? If so, perhaps you have access to one of them but not the other.